# Gorm Jsonb type stored as bytea

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm

I'm using a locally hosted postgres DB to test queries to a postgres DB in production. The production database has an `info` field of type `jsonb`; and I'm trying to mimic this schema locally when using gorm's `AutoMigrate`. The model I've defined is below:

```
import "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"

type Event struct {
    ...
    Info postgres.Jsonb
    ...
}
```

But when I query JSON attributes, e.g. `stmt.Where("info->>'attr' = value")`, I get the following error:

```
...
Message:"operator does not exist: bytea ->> unknown", Detail:"", Hint:"No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.",
...
```

This query works however in the production environment. It seems that the `Info` field is being stored as `bytea` instead of `jsonb`. I'm aware that I can do `stmt.Where("encode(info, "escape")::jsonb->>'attr' = value")`, but I'd prefer to mimic the production environment more closely (if possible) than change the query to support these unit tests.

I've tried using type tags in the model (e.g. `gorm:"type=jsonb"`) as well as defining my own JSON type implmementing the valuer, scanner, and `GormDataTypeInterface` as suggested [here](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html). None of these approaches have automigrated the type as `jsonb`.

Is there any way to ensure `AutoMigrate` creates a table with type `jsonb`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem, type `JsonB` is automigrated to `bytea`. I solved it by adding the tag `gorm:"type:jsonb"`. It's also mentioned in your question, but you're using `gorm:"type=jsonb"`, which is not correct.

Comment: You are a saviour. Thanks a lot. You saved my whole day's struggle.